# Confused! RSUs vs. Base Salary Hike

Tags: salary, negotiation

I'm on the verge of jumping ships from a Fortune 500 firm where I've been working for 10 years to another Fortune 500 firm in a different industry. The role and org at the new firm seem better. Also, my present role at the current firm doesn't excite me much now.

At the firm I work at currently, the current RSUs that vest for me every year are worth as much as the base salary. Having been a top performer, I was granted RSUs every year in the past eight years, which is a feat in itself. My annual RSUs are worth 100% of the base package at the current market price of the stock (not the price at which the stocks were initially granted to me). This company's stock has simply exploded over the past couple of years; it is one of those rare meteoric success stories. Even from the present level, which is 10X the stock price five years ago, the stock could triple in value in five years, analysts say. I also have a hugely profitable ESPP plan at the current firm, which is benefiting from the stock price rise.

I may be granted RSUs in the future, but there is no guarantee. Additionally, given the current stock price, the firm is expected to go tight-fisted with stock grants this year. Also, last year, my role was shuffled into a new non-engineering org that is known to grant way fewer stock grants when compared to the engineering org from where most of my grants so far have come.

The new firm has offered me a 66% hike over the base salary and a ~15% variable annual bonus. In addition, they're also compensating me, through  joining and retention bonuses, for the value (as of the date of negotiations) of the unvested RSUs that'll vest for me in the current financial year.

In effect, my total compensation over the next three years might be flat if I make the move. The non-monetary growth seems interesting. The new company, stable as it looks, isn't doing as phenomenally as my current employer, though.

Given a better role in a better org, would you make this move? Please advise.

Comment: I'm the OP. Thanks for the answer, Chris. Well, something like that, but what makes me think and rethink is the opportunity cost of leaving behind RSUs whose value may still treble. Also, the ESPP plan (until at least mid 2019) is hugely profitable. Every penny I invest in it becomes 215%. Then, in July 2019, the lock in price will reset, and the returns will become muted. I don't know if I'm introducing too many variables into the equation. The new firm is offering me a higher position. It is also in the "Internet" industry, so my opportunities down the line may be better. Also, their retenti

Answer (score 4):

So the new role is 180% of your current salary (90% total compensation) plus 100% of this year's RSU vesting. If you spread that signing bonus over 5 years you still end up whole for 5 years at 200% salary as before.

Also noting that you seem to expect a decline in RSU vesting going forward with your new role in the current company - so it sounds like you're not losing any money but may in fact come out slightly ahead with the 1 year RSU signing bonus.

Given the role is better why not take the new job?